# ReactJS: Getting Failed to Compile Error While Starting the Server

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in ReactJS. Just after finishing a course on the basics of React and Redux. I have started a new Udemy course entitled "React Data Visualization - Build a Cryptocurrency Dashboard." I am facing a problem in lecture 4 while trying to start the server with `yarn start` command:

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Cannot find file: 'index.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\App\app'.
```

Here are my codes on `index.js` file under `app` directory:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        Hello World
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Here are my codes on `index.js` file under `src` directory:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

How can I fix the issue?

You can find the project files here.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u-8mCYSWZtXPbIqELKsF33FOiXb3yrkH

**Edit 1**: I am adding the codes inside package.json file, as suggested by @Wesgur:

```
{
  "name": "cryptodash",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit 2**: I am adding the image to show the folder structure, as suggested by @Madhavan.V:
[image]

Comment: Can you also add your `package.json`?

Comment: @Wesgur I have added the codes of `package.json` file to the question.

Comment: @Shawn Check the import `import App from './App';`

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: @Madhavan.V Here is the link the project files: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u-8mCYSWZtXPbIqELKsF33FOiXb3yrkH/ . Would you please take a look at it?

Comment: @Madhavan.V I have added an image that shows the folder structure to the question. Please, take a look at it.

Comment: Your `index.js` file is outside of the `app` folder.

Comment: @Shawn Can you try to change the import in `src/index` to `import App from './app';`

Comment: @MujiburrehmanAnsari As shown in the course, one `index.js` file will be inside `app` folder and another `index.js` file will be outside the `app` folder.

Comment: I think you are importing from `./App` instead `./app`

Comment: the main index.js file which is inside the src folder gets loaded in your index.html file in the div with id `root`. It contains all the files of your react app. The place where yor are importing App.js in your that index.js, the importing is wrong as the path is wrong. please check.

Comment: @Madhavan.V You are absolutely right! Please, add your comment as the answer. I will choose it as the right one. :)

Comment: It is just a typo. Better you can delete your answer. :)

Comment: @Madhavan.V I have seen that a man named Prakhar Mittal has added an answer to the question. Is it your second account. Should I choose it as the correct answer?

Comment: LOL.. I've only one account. I felt question answers with these kind of typos can be removed from Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Madhavan.V But you have given me the right answer! You deserve upvote! Also, your answer deserves to be chosen as the right one! Nonetheless, let me know if I am really required to delete the question.

Comment: I've added as an answer finally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Shawan It is just a typo change the App import statement in src/index from `import App from './App';` to `import App from './app';`.

Answer (score 0):

import App from './app';
this will import your index.js of app folder.